# Infinite loop in card game "War"- Java

Tags: java

So when I run my program, about every 1 in 4 times it will just start infinitely looping. The other times it works fine. Note that my game of war isn't technically completely correct. I'm not quite sure how to store the cards the players win into their own separate decks and then shuffle those back in once they run out of cards. And my method for dueling probably isn't the best. It's really long. For the time being I need to fix this looping issue.

Oh, I'm also only using 24 cards and the only cards used are 5,6,7,8,9, and 10 from each suit.

Main

```
import java.util.Random;
public class Main {
static Player player1 = new Player("player1");
static Player player2 = new Player("player2");

static Card[] deck = {new Card("Hearts", 5), new Card("Hearts", 6), new Card("Hearts", 7), new Card("Hearts", 8), new Card("Hearts", 9), new Card("Hearts", 10),
        new Card("Diamonds", 5), new Card("Diamonds", 6), new Card("Diamonds", 7), new Card("Diamonds", 8), new Card("Diamonds", 9), new Card("Diamonds", 10),
        new Card("Spades", 5), new Card("Spades", 6), new Card("Spades", 7), new Card("Spades", 8), new Card("Spades", 9), new Card("Spades", 10),
        new Card("Clubs", 5), new Card("Clubs", 6), new Card("Clubs", 7), new Card("Clubs", 8), new Card("Clubs", 9), new Card("Clubs", 10)
};

public static void main(String args[]){
    shuffleArray(deck);
    dealDeck();
    int i=0;
    while (i<1){
        printCard();
        if(player1.cards.size()>0 && player2.cards.size()>0){
            Duel();
        }
        else{
            if(player1.numCards>player2.numCards){
                System.out.println("Player 1 has won.");
                i++;
            }
            else if(player2.numCards>player1.numCards){
                System.out.println("Player 2 has won.");
                i++;
            }
            duelsWon();
            totalCompares();
        }
    }
}

private static void shuffleArray(Card[] array)
{
    int index;
    Card temp;
    Random random = new Random();
    for (int i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--)
    {
        index = random.nextInt(i + 1);
        temp = array[index];
        array[index] = array[i];
        array[i] = temp;
    }
}
public static void dealDeck(){
    for(int i=0;i<24;i=i+2){
        player1.dealCard(deck[i]);
        player2.dealCard(deck[i+1]);
    }
}
public static void duelsWon(){
    System.out.printf("%-20s %-20s\n", player1.name+"'s duels won", player2.name+"'s duels won");
    System.out.printf("%-20s %-20s\n", player1.duelsWon, player2.duelsWon);
}
public static void totalCompares(){
    System.out.printf("%-10s\n", "Total Compares");
    System.out.printf("%-10s\n", player1.totalCompares+player2.totalCompares);
}
public static void printCard(){
    System.out.printf("%-20s %-20s\n", player1.name, player2.name);
    for(int i = 0;i<24;i++){
        System.out.printf("%-20s %-20s\n", player1.getCard(i), player2.getCard(i));
    } System.out.println();
}
public static void Duel(){
    Card p1 = player1.drawCard();
    Card p2 = player2.drawCard();
    System.out.println(p1);
    System.out.println(p2);
    if(p1.compareTo(p2)>0){
        player1.dealCard(p1);
        player1.dealCard(p2);
        player1.duelsWon++;
        player1.totalCompares++;
    }
    else if(p2.compareTo(p1)>0){
        player2.dealCard(p1);
        player2.dealCard(p2);
        player2.duelsWon++;
        player2.totalCompares++;
    }
    else{
        if(player1.cards.size()>=3 && player2.cards.size()>3){
            int i=0;
            while(i<1){
                Card p1C1 = player1.drawCard();
                Card p1C2 = player1.drawCard();
                Card p1C3 = player1.drawCard();
                Card p2C1 = player2.drawCard();
                Card p2C2 = player2.drawCard();
                Card p2C3 = player2.drawCard();
                if(p1C3.compareTo(p2C3)>0){
                    player1.dealCard(p1);
                    player1.dealCard(p2);
                    player1.dealCard(p1C1);
                    player1.dealCard(p1C2);
                    player1.dealCard(p1C3);
                    player1.dealCard(p2C1);
                    player1.dealCard(p2C2);
                    player1.dealCard(p2C3);
                    player1.duelsWon++;
                    player1.totalCompares++;
                    i++;
                }
                else if(p2C3.compareTo(p1C3)>0){
                    player2.dealCard(p1);
                    player2.dealCard(p2);
                    player2.dealCard(p1C1);
                    player2.dealCard(p1C2);
                    player2.dealCard(p1C3);
                    player2.dealCard(p2C1);
                    player2.dealCard(p2C2);
                    player2.dealCard(p2C3);
                    player2.duelsWon++;
                    player2.totalCompares++;
                    i++;
                }
                else{
                    if(p1C2.compareTo(p2C2)>0){
                        player1.dealCard(p1);
                        player1.dealCard(p2);
                        player1.dealCard(p1C1);
                        player1.dealCard(p1C2);
                        player1.dealCard(p1C3);
                        player1.dealCard(p2C1);
                        player1.dealCard(p2C2);
                        player1.dealCard(p2C3);
                        player1.duelsWon++;
                        player1.totalCompares++;
                        i++;
                    }
                    else if(p2C2.compareTo(p1C2)>0){
                        player2.dealCard(p1);
                        player2.dealCard(p2);
                        player2.dealCard(p1C1);
                        player2.dealCard(p1C2);
                        player2.dealCard(p1C3);
                        player2.dealCard(p2C1);
                        player2.dealCard(p2C2);
                        player2.dealCard(p2C3);
                        player2.duelsWon++;
                        player2.totalCompares++;
                        i++;
                    }
                    else{
                        if(p1C1.compareTo(p2C1)>0){
                            player1.dealCard(p1);
                            player1.dealCard(p2);
                            player1.dealCard(p1C1);
                            player1.dealCard(p1C2);
                            player1.dealCard(p1C3);
                            player1.dealCard(p2C1);
                            player1.dealCard(p2C2);
                            player1.dealCard(p2C3);
                            player1.duelsWon++;
                            player1.totalCompares++;
                            i++;
                        }
                        else if(p2C1.compareTo(p1C1)>0){
                            player2.dealCard(p1);
                            player2.dealCard(p2);
                            player2.dealCard(p1C1);
                            player2.dealCard(p1C2);
                            player2.dealCard(p1C3);
                            player2.dealCard(p2C1);
                            player2.dealCard(p2C2);
                            player2.dealCard(p2C3);
                            player2.duelsWon++;
                            player2.totalCompares++;
                            i++;
                        }
                        else{

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else{
            if(player2.cards.size()==3){
                Card p1C1 = player1.drawCard();
                Card p1C2 = player1.drawCard();
                Card p1C3 = player1.drawCard();
                Card p2C1 = player2.drawCard();
                Card p2C2 = player2.drawCard();
                Card p2C3 = player2.drawCard();
                if(p1C3.compareTo(p2C3)>0){
                    player1.dealCard(p1C1);
                    player1.dealCard(p1C2);
                    player1.dealCard(p1C3);
                    player1.dealCard(p2C1);
                    player1.dealCard(p2C2);
                    player1.dealCard(p2C3);
                }
                else if(p2C3.compareTo(p2C3)>0){
                    player2.dealCard(p1C1);
                    player2.dealCard(p1C2);
                    player2.dealCard(p1C3);
                    player2.dealCard(p2C1);
                    player2.dealCard(p2C2);
                    player2.dealCard(p2C3);
                }
                else{
                    if(p1C2.compareTo(p2C2)>0){
                        player1.dealCard(p1C1);
                        player1.dealCard(p1C2);
                        player1.dealCard(p1C3);
                        player1.dealCard(p2C1);
                        player1.dealCard(p2C2);
                        player1.dealCard(p2C3);
                    }
                    else if(p2C2.compareTo(p1C2)>0){
                        player2.dealCard(p1C1);
                        player2.dealCard(p1C2);
                        player2.dealCard(p1C3);
                        player2.dealCard(p2C1);
                        player2.dealCard(p2C2);
                        player2.dealCard(p2C3);
                    }
                    else{
                        if(p1C1.compareTo(p2C1)>0){
                            player1.dealCard(p1C1);
                            player1.dealCard(p1C2);
                            player1.dealCard(p1C3);
                            player1.dealCard(p2C1);
                            player1.dealCard(p2C2);
                            player1.dealCard(p2C3);
                        }
                        else if(p2C1.compareTo(p1C1)>0){
                            player2.dealCard(p1C1);
                            player2.dealCard(p1C2);
                            player2.dealCard(p1C3);
                            player2.dealCard(p2C1);
                            player2.dealCard(p2C2);
                            player2.dealCard(p2C3);
                        }
                        else{
                            player1.dealCard(p1C1);
                            player1.dealCard(p1C2);
                            player1.dealCard(p1C3);
                            player1.dealCard(p2C1);
                            player1.dealCard(p2C2);
                            player1.dealCard(p2C3);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            else if(player1.cards.size()==3){
                Card p1C1 = player1.drawCard();
                Card p1C2 = player1.drawCard();
                Card p1C3 = player1.drawCard();
                Card p2C1 = player2.drawCard();
                Card p2C2 = player2.drawCard();
                Card p2C3 = player2.drawCard();
                if(p1C3.compareTo(p2C3)>0){
                    player1.dealCard(p1C1);
                    player1.dealCard(p1C2);
                    player1.dealCard(p1C3);
                    player1.dealCard(p2C1);
                    player1.dealCard(p2C2);
                    player1.dealCard(p2C3);
                }
                else if(p2C3.compareTo(p2C3)>0){
                    player2.dealCard(p1C1);
                    player2.dealCard(p1C2);
                    player2.dealCard(p1C3);
                    player2.dealCard(p2C1);
                    player2.dealCard(p2C2);
                    player2.dealCard(p2C3);
                }
                else{
                    if(p1C2.compareTo(p2C2)>0){
                        player1.dealCard(p1C1);
                        player1.dealCard(p1C2);
                        player1.dealCard(p1C3);
                        player1.dealCard(p2C1);
                        player1.dealCard(p2C2);
                        player1.dealCard(p2C3);
                    }
                    else if(p2C2.compareTo(p1C1)>0){
                        player2.dealCard(p1C1);
                        player2.dealCard(p1C2);
                        player2.dealCard(p1C3);
                        player2.dealCard(p2C1);
                        player2.dealCard(p2C2);
                        player2.dealCard(p2C3);
                    }
                    else{
                        if(p1C1.compareTo(p2C1)>0){
                            player1.dealCard(p1C1);
                            player1.dealCard(p1C2);
                            player1.dealCard(p1C3);
                            player1.dealCard(p2C1);
                            player1.dealCard(p2C2);
                            player1.dealCard(p2C3);
                        }
                        else if(p2C1.compareTo(p1C1)>0){
                            player2.dealCard(p1C1);
                            player2.dealCard(p1C2);
                            player2.dealCard(p1C3);
                            player2.dealCard(p2C1);
                            player2.dealCard(p2C2);
                            player2.dealCard(p2C3);
                        }
                        else{
                            player2.dealCard(p1C1);
                            player2.dealCard(p1C2);
                            player2.dealCard(p1C3);
                            player2.dealCard(p2C1);
                            player2.dealCard(p2C2);
                            player2.dealCard(p2C3);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            else if(player2.cards.size()==2){
                Card p1C1 = player1.drawCard();
                Card p1C2 = player1.drawCard();
                Card p2C1 = player2.drawCard();
                Card p2C2 = player2.drawCard();
                if(p1C2.compareTo(p2C2)>0){
                    player1.dealCard(p1C1);
                    player1.dealCard(p1C2);
                    player1.dealCard(p2C1);
                    player1.dealCard(p2C2);
                }
                else if(p2C2.compareTo(p1C2)>0){
                    player2.dealCard(p1C1);
                    player2.dealCard(p1C2);
                    player2.dealCard(p2C1);
                    player2.dealCard(p2C2);
                }
                else{
                    if(p1C1.compareTo(p2C1)>0){
                        player1.dealCard(p1C1);
                        player1.dealCard(p1C2);
                        player1.dealCard(p2C1);
                        player1.dealCard(p2C2);
                    }
                    else if(p2C1.compareTo(p1C1)>0){
                        player2.dealCard(p1C1);
                        player2.dealCard(p1C2);
                        player2.dealCard(p2C1);
                        player2.dealCard(p2C2);
                    }
                    else{
                        player1.dealCard(p1C1);
                        player1.dealCard(p1C2);
                        player1.dealCard(p2C1);
                        player1.dealCard(p2C2);
                    }
                }
            }
            else if(player1.cards.size()==2){
                Card p1C1 = player1.drawCard();
                Card p1C2 = player1.drawCard();
                Card p2C1 = player2.drawCard();
                Card p2C2 = player2.drawCard();
                if(p1C2.compareTo(p2C2)>0){
                    player1.dealCard(p1C1);
                    player1.dealCard(p1C2);
                    player1.dealCard(p2C1);
                    player1.dealCard(p2C2);
                }
                else if(p2C2.compareTo(p1C2)>0){
                    player2.dealCard(p1C1);
                    player2.dealCard(p1C2);
                    player2.dealCard(p2C1);
                    player2.dealCard(p2C2);
                }
                else{
                    if(p1C1.compareTo(p2C1)>0){
                        player1.dealCard(p1C1);
                        player1.dealCard(p1C2);
                        player1.dealCard(p2C1);
                        player1.dealCard(p2C2);
                    }
                    else if(p2C1.compareTo(p1C1)>0){
                        player2.dealCard(p1C1);
                        player2.dealCard(p1C2);
                        player2.dealCard(p2C1);
                        player2.dealCard(p2C2);
                    }
                    else{
                        player2.dealCard(p1C1);
                        player2.dealCard(p1C2);
                        player2.dealCard(p2C1);
                        player2.dealCard(p2C2);
                    }
                }
            }
            else if(player2.cards.size()==1){
                Card p1C1 = player1.drawCard();
                Card p2C1 = player2.drawCard();
                if(p1C1.compareTo(p2C1)>0){
                    player1.dealCard(p1C1);
                    player1.dealCard(p2C1);
                }
                else if(p2C1.compareTo(p1C1)>0){
                    player2.dealCard(p1C1);
                    player2.dealCard(p2C1);
                }
                else{
                    player1.dealCard(p1C1);
                    player1.dealCard(p2C1);
                }
            }
            else if(player1.cards.size()==1){
                Card p1C1 = player1.drawCard();
                Card p2C1 = player2.drawCard();
                if(p1C1.compareTo(p2C1)>0){
                    player1.dealCard(p1C1);
                    player1.dealCard(p2C1);
                }
                else if(p2C1.compareTo(p1C1)>0){
                    player2.dealCard(p1C1);
                    player2.dealCard(p2C1);
                }
                else{
                    player2.dealCard(p1C1);
                    player2.dealCard(p2C1);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Player

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class Player {
public ArrayList<Card> cards=new ArrayList<Card>();
public int numCards;
public int topOfDeck;
public String name;
public int duelsWon;
public int totalCompares;

public Player(String name){
    this.name=name;
    numCards=0;
    topOfDeck = 0;
    duelsWon = 0;
    totalCompares = 0;
}
public void dealCard(Card newCard){
    cards.add(newCard);
    numCards++;
}

public String getCard(int n){
    if(n < cards.size()) {
        return cards.get(n).toString();
    }else{
        return "\\";
    }
}
public Card drawCard(){
    Card c = cards.remove(0);
    topOfDeck++;
    topOfDeck = topOfDeck % 24;
    return c;
}
}
```

Card

```
public class Card implements Comparable<Card> {
private String suit;
private int number;

public Card(String suit, int number){
    this.suit = suit;
    this.number = number;
}

public String getSuit(){
    return suit;
}
public int getNumber(){
    return number;
}
@Override
public int compareTo(Card otherCard){
    if (this.number>otherCard.getNumber()){
        return 1;
    }else if(otherCard.getNumber()>this.number){
        return -1;
    }else{
        return 0;
    }
}
@Override
public String toString(){
    return number+" of "+suit;
}

}
```

Comment: Have you been able to determine which loop is causing the infinite loop? For example, have you tried to add a debugging `System.out.print("loop1")` to any of the loops? At least with that we have an idea which of the loops you are getting stuck in since we will be logging the problem loop.

Comment: I haven't but I will try that next. I'm about to head out but when I get back I'll give it a shot. Thanks.

Comment: Please try to provide an [MCVE (Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is problem, but you need to have else branch in your if/else if branching to cover all possibilities. There is possibility that both players have same amount of cards.

```
while (i<1){
            printCard();
            if(player1.cards.size()>0 && player2.cards.size()>0){
                Duel();
            }
            else{
                if(player1.numCards>player2.numCards){
                    System.out.println("Player 1 has won.");
                    i++;
                }
                else if(player2.numCards>player1.numCards){
                    System.out.println("Player 2 has won.");
                    i++;
                }else{
                    break;
                    // or put i++;
                }
                duelsWon();
                totalCompares();
            }
        }
```

Comment: That didn't fix the problem but I didn't notice that. Thanks, I added it in.

Comment: its not the only place - make sure you handle all cases everywhere. this is a very complicated code with tons of if-else, think about ways to simplify this... you'll find bugs more easily that way